# In which the real number system that sum of geometric progression involve?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to know about  sum of geometric progression

a and r
Are they real number it integer .. Etc ?

Comment: This question makes almost no sense: besides the language's problems, lots of info are missing.

Comment: What is your question? What you have written is impossible to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula

$$(1-r)(a+ar+ar^2+....+ar^n)=a(1-r^{n+1})$$

hold in any ring. Thus it is true in integers, rationals, reals and complex numbers.

Now, if you want to divide by $1-r$, you need "$\frac{1}{1-r}$" to make sense in the numbers you have. In particular, that formula holds in any field, as long as $r\neq 1$, and it also holds in Integral domains, as long as $1-r$ divides the RHS.

Hence.

$$a+ar+ar^2+....+ar^n=a \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

is true in rationals, real and complex numbers. Moreover, is $a,r$ are integers, since the formula holds in rationals, and the LHS is integer, it follows that both sides are integers and equal. Thus formula also holds in integers.